# Need margins between elements in QML ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I need margins between elements in QML ListView. With this code I get margin of column of elements, but I need margin between each element:

```
    ListModel {
         id: listModel

         ListElement {
             name: "Apple"
         }
         ListElement {
             name: "Banana"
         }
 }

Component {
    id: listDelegate

    Rectangle {
    width: 250; height: 100
    anchors.margins: 30
    color: "green"

    Text {
        id: itexItem
        anchors.leftMargin: 20
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        font.pixelSize: 40
        text: name
    }

    }
}
ListView {
       id: listView
       anchors.fill: parent;
       anchors.margins: 50
       model: listModel
       delegate: listDelegate
       focus: true
 }
```

I get margin between box of list element. Is it work fine. I need margin between each element of ListView. I need column like:

```
Element  "Apple"
margin
Element  "Banana"
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add:

```
spacing: value
```

to your `ListView` properties.

Comment: Note that using `spacing` will make partially off-Window delegates disappear when animation ends, which is really ugly. One way to fix that is to set the `width` of the delegate to be desired width + your spacing. That can be troublesome with highlight around the delegate though, as the highlight will include the spacing.